# adb shell permission denied samsung s I9003

Tags: android, adb

I copied sqlite database on /mnt/sdcard on samsung s I9003 device (2.3.6) and trying to access db thorugh adb shell .Giving error permission denied.
I tried

```
C:\Users\abc>adb shell
$ su
su
su: permission denied
$
```

I also tried to pull database from ddms it done successfully .But data is not shown is table.

This work perfectly for Micromax funbook (ICS) tablet but for samsung s I9003 not worked

Comment: Does `sudo su` works? Is your device rooted?

Comment: Are you rooted? Try `adb remount`

Comment: I tried both way ..but not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Run adb shell and how to get # instead of $ for root permission : Android](http://chethaka.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/run-adb-shell-and-get-instead-of/). Hope this helps.